# How can I capture a running cumulative count of unique entries by group in R / Dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that shows unique "person.id's" for each calendar day in a month. I'm trying to get a cumulative count of unique ID's by calendar day. For example, the correct output for the attached image would be:

> calendar day 1-- 4 (A, B, C, D)
>
> calendar day 1:2-- 6 (A, B, C, D, E, F)
>
> calendar day 1:3-- 10 ( A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J)

The full data set is grouped by month, so ideally the cumulative unique count output is tied to a group (in other words, when calendar day turns back to one, the cumulative count resets).

I've tried summarizing by n_distinct(person.id), but I can't figure out how to get that cumulative for day 1:n.

Note: I'm conversant in dplyr but not so much data.table and if possible would love to have ideas for execution in dplyr...

Thanks!

[image: Data frame]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after?

```
df <- data.frame(person_id = c('A','B','C','D','A','B','D','E','F','D','G','H','I','J'),
             calendar_day = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
             month = c('1/31/17'))

numvals <- cummax(as.numeric(factor(df$person_id)))
aggregate(numvals, list(month = df$month, calendar_day=df$calendar_day), max)
```